# How do I turn off QuickE for just one module?

Tags: 2sxc

I have a page with a few modules on it. On one, the QuickE menu is not useful and actually gets in the way of other functionality (DNN's action menus AND 2sxc Edit toolbar). I found the docs and was able to turn it off for the whole page, but that is not what I want. I do want it on for all the other modules, just not this one. This one is a 2sxc custom app and I was hoping to be able to disable QuickE from the View code. Is that possible or supported?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight-forward, you can disable QuickE for a certain section of the theme, and that section can of course be your module. Technically QuickE scans for the html attribute `quick-edit-config` and respects that for everything inside that html-node. See https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Html-Js-%24quickE

Comment: Could you re-read what I wrote? What I am asking is - I need/want QuickE on for the page, I just have 1 module where I need it to NOT 'attach.' I have successfully gotten it turned off, but it appears to be all or nothing. Again, I have 5 to 20 modules on the pages and just one of them needs it off.

Comment: @Accuraty-Jeremy that's what should work. Let me explain: if it's on on the whole page, but you have a container for the module where it should be off, put that attribute on that container - and inside the module it will be off. 
Maybe you could explain what you expect when it's off - I assume it's about inner-content, but I could be wrong.