# 2SXC: Disable QuickE for a Specific Module/View

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I know there is an old thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590293/how-do-i-turn-off-quicke-for-just-one-module) on this, but we can't seem to resolve the same issue running DNN v9.12 and 2SXC v16.7 after reviewing all the docs [here](https://docs.2sxc.org/js-code/quick-e/index.html).

We do have QuickE enabled on the skin like this and it works site-wide:

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="Edit" tagname="QuickEdit" src="~/DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/DnnWebForms/Skins/QuickEdit.ascx" %>
<Edit:QuickEdit runat="server" />
```

When we try and disable QuickE in a razor view for one specific module then all the QuickE buttons disappear from the page:

```
<div @Edit.Attribute("quick-edit-config", new { modules = new { enable = false }})>
    ...
</div>
```

...or...

```
<div @Edit.Attribute("quick-edit-config", new { enable = false })>
    ...
</div>
```

We based our attempts based on this comment in the referenced post by @iJungleBoy:

> if it's on on the whole page, but you have a container for the module
> where it should be off, put that attribute on that container - and
> inside the module it will be off.

We also tried enabling QuickE via the quick-edit-config attribute within parent elements of the skin, but that didn't work either.

Thank you for any guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on this since forever, but IMHO it's hierarchical.

So if you have it on in the skin, and then a `div` in your Razor with the quickE that should result in QuickE turning off inside that view.

If you want to turn in off *outside* that view then I'm not actually sure what you're doing.

- Normally you turn it off *inside* a view to prevent inner-content
- or you turn it off on the page to only allow inner content - eg on a Blog-details page where the user could accidentally add more modules to the details-page, which is not expected.

Comment: We're trying to turn it off for just one single 2sxc view, but keep it active on the whole page otherwise. Anytime we use quick-edit-config to set it off, it disables it for the whole page. We didn't want to open a bug report, but we do see this behavior also mentioned in github here: [link](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2456#issuecomment-934680423)